# Error de Sintaxis en SQL y Java

Tags: java

Quiero introducir los datos de este Array, en la tabla de una BD en MySQLWorkbech, el problema que tengo es que me salta un error de Sintaxis en la sentencia de SQL, y me gustaria que me dijeseis donde esta el error.

Esta es la clase que uso para poder conectarme a la BD.

Y este es el metodo en el que estoy intentando introducir los datos en la tabla requerida.

```
public class Examen {

public static void main(String[]args) {
     Examen e = new Examen();
     e.introduceDatosEnTablaJugadores();
}

    static DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");

Jugador[] listaJugadores = { 
        new Jugador("123F", "BALE", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 0, 15),
        new Jugador("124F", "INIESTA", LocalDate.parse("15081979", fmt), 183, 1, 7),
        new Jugador("125F", "BALE2", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 0, 1),
        new Jugador("126F", "JOAQUIN3", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 2, 5),
        new Jugador("127F", "INIESTA1", LocalDate.parse("15081969", fmt), 183, 1, 3),
        new Jugador("128F", "BALE4", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 0, 5),
        new Jugador("129F", "INIESTA2", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 1, 0),
        new Jugador("134F", "JOAQUIN5", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 2, 2),
        new Jugador("423F", "BALE8", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 0, 5),
        new Jugador("524F", "INIESTA5", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 1, 4),
        new Jugador("625F", "JOAQUIN7", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 2, 6),
        new Jugador("724F", "INIESTA", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 1, 10),
        new Jugador("825F", "BALE2", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 0, 15),
        new Jugador("923F", "JOAQUIN3", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 2, 5),
        new Jugador("224F", "INIESTA9", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 1, 2),
        new Jugador("325F", "BALE9", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 0, 1),
        new Jugador("424F", "JOAQUIN2", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 2, 0),
        new Jugador("625F", "JOAQUIN5", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 2, 1),
        new Jugador("823F", "BALE6", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 0, 7),
        new Jugador("724F", "INIESTA3", LocalDate.parse("15081999", fmt), 183, 1, 4),
        new Jugador("925F", "BALE7", LocalDate.parse("15081996", fmt), 182, 0, 5) 
};

public void introduceDatosEnTablaJugadores() {
    try {
    BaseDatos bd = new BaseDatos("localhost", "mysqlbd", "root", "");
    Connection conexion = bd.getConexion();
    Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement();
    for (int i = 0; i< listaJugadores.length; i++) {
        String sql= "INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES (" + listaJugadores[i] + ")";
        System.out.println(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    stmt.close();
    conexion.close(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Y cuál es el error? Agrégalo

Comment: Deberias de poner el texto que te da el error asi, podremos atacar el problema mas efectivamente y no especular

Answer (score 0):

En Java **todos** los objetos tienen por defecto el método `toString()` que se encarga de representarlos en cadena y su implementación por defecto consiste en imprimir el nombre de la clase junto con su ubicación en memoria.

Por esta razón, suponiendo que la primera posición libre en la memoria es la 500 si le mandas en código

`new Jugador("123F", "BALE", LocalDate.parse("15081998", fmt), 182, 0, 15);`

al llamar al método `toString()` debería de darte `Jugador@500`.

El momento de usar el operador `+` para concatenar, estás llamando al método `toString()` sin darte cuenta, por lo que el código

`INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES (" + listaJugadores[i] + ")`

te generaría en nuestro ejemplo

`INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES (Jugador@500)`

lo cual representa a simple vista un error de sintaxis.

Puedes corroborar lo que te digo fácilmente al agregar un simple

```
System.out.println(listaJugadores[i]);
```

antes de crear tu variable `sql`.

Tiene muchas formas de solucionarlo, desde redefinir la forma en que se genera la representación en cadena para esa clase de objetos o extraer de cada (instancia de) `Jugador` los valores en concreto que vas a poner (en el orden exacto en que se deben de poner ).